# "select all" check box not working

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create domain search form. There will be check boxes with individual domain names as well as a select all or search all check box. When clicked on it all the other checkboxes should get selected and on unchecking it all the other check boxes should get unchecked too. Now here is the script i am trying to use but for some reason it wont work

Script

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.js'></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){

$("#checkAll").change(function() {
    $(":checkbox").attr("checked", this.checked);
});
$(".others").change(function() {
    if (!$('input.others[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)').length)
        $("#checkAll").attr('checked', true);
    if (!$('input.others[type=checkbox]:checked').length)
        $("#checkAll").attr('checked', false);
});
});//]]>
```

HTML Part

```
<div class="tran_form">
                    <form id="form3" action="whmcs/cart.php?a=add&domain=register" method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="52fe670c7c55b28b9e76c677afd97580147cbb5e" />
                        <fieldset class="d-block">
                            <div class="margin-bot">
                                <div class="inp_title">www.</div>
                                <label class="input-1">
                                    <input type="text" name="sld">
                                </label>
                                <a href="#" class="button-2" onClick="document.getElementById('form3').submit()">Search Now!</a>
                                <div class="clear"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="wrapper">
                                <div class="col-1">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="tlds[]" value=".in" class="others">
                                    <label>.in</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-1">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="tlds[]" value=".com" class="others">
                                    <label>.com</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-1">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="tlds[]" value=".net" class="others">
                                    <label>.net</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-1">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="tlds[]" value=".org" class="others">
                                    <label>.org</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-1">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="tlds[]" value=".biz" class="others">
                                    <label>.biz</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-1">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="tlds[]" value=".info" class="others">
                                    <label>.info</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-1">
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="checkAll">
                                    <label class="reg2 color-1">Search All</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                    </form>
                </div>
```

Any idea what i am doing wrong? doesn't seem to work. When I am using a toned down version of this script as shown below

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
$(window).load(function(){
$("#checkAll").change(function() {
$(":checkbox").attr("checked", this.checked);
});
$(".others").change(function() {
    if (!$('input.others[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)').length)
        $("#checkAll").attr('checked', true);
    if (!$('input.others[type=checkbox]:checked').length)
        $("#checkAll").attr('checked', false);
});
});//]]> 
</script>
</head>
<body> 
<div>
<input type="checkbox" value="" id="checkAll">
<input type="checkbox" value="a" class="others">
<input type="checkbox" value="b" class="others">
<input type="checkbox" value="c" class="others">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The select all is working just fine but when i try to adopt it into the site i am working on it wont work.

Answer (score 0):

Place the javascript inside the `<head>` of your HTML and the `checkAll` function will work properly. [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/pz6wB/)

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.js'>
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ 
    $(window).load(function(){
    $("#checkAll").change(function() {
    $(":checkbox").attr("checked", this.checked);
    });
    $(".others").change(function() {
        if (!$('input.others[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)').length)
            $("#checkAll").attr('checked', true);
        if (!$('input.others[type=checkbox]:checked').length)
            $("#checkAll").attr('checked', false);
    });
    });//]]>
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="tran_form">
    .....
```

Comment: I tried to find out the error and created a simple html page with just the script and the form content and see it works. But when i implement it in the actual page it doesnt work. Don't understand why could u look it up if i send u the link of the page which i am trying to implement this code on?

Comment: here is the link to the page where i have implemented the code but it doesn't work [link](http://cheap-webhosting.co.in/check)

Comment: Well, removing the `style.css` file solved the problem, so I suggest you look into anything that is related to `checkbox` and `input` in `style.css` and might interfere with the checkbox `checkAll` functionality.

Comment: looked into it and here is the css code    /* -- * Checkboxes * -- */
#form2 span.jqTransformCheckboxWrapper{display:block;float:left; padding:10px 0 0 0;}
#form2 a.jqTransformCheckbox {background: transparent url(../images/checkbox.png) 0 0px no-repeat;vertical-align: middle;height:15px;width:15px;display:block;/*display: -moz-inline-block;*/}
/* -- * Checked * -- */
#form2 .jqTransformCheckboxWrapper a.jqTransformChecked {background: transparent url(../images/checkbox.png) 0 -16px no-repeat;}    removing them makes the select all work fine. Any ideas as to what can be done?

Comment: You know that if you delete *all this code* it makes the select all work properly. You know that if you use *all this code* the select all doesn't work. What you need to do now, is remove all this code, and insert one item at a time (e.g `#form2 span.jqTransformCheckboxWrapper{display:block;float:left; padding:10px 0 0 0;}`, save and check if it makes the select all not working. If it doesn't, continue to the next item. If it does make your select all not working, skip it and don't add this item to the CSS. Also, I suggest you do all of this offline, instead of re-uploading the style.css file.

Comment: on further consideration discovered that my .jqTransformCheckboxWrapper function is creating this problem. Thinking about just removing the css part and using the select as it is though it will make me compromise on the looks of the page but i dont have the time or energy to go through the jquery functions too. What do u suggest?

Comment: Is it `.tran_form form span.jqTransformCheckboxWrapper{display:block;float:left; padding:0 9px 0 0;}` **or** `.tran_form form .jqTransformCheckboxWrapper a.jqTransformChecked {background: transparent url(../images/checkbox2.png) 0 -20px no-repeat;}` ?